# Bernoulli Equation for Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]
Is this formula still available if $n$ is a negative number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **yes, $n$ can be any real number.**

The general form of a Bernoulli ODE is

$$y' + p(x)y = q(x)y^n $$
Let $n = -k^2$, so $n \le 0$.

$$y^{k^2}y' + p(x)y^{1+k^2} = q(x)$$

Now let $z = y^{1+k^2} \implies z' = (1+k^2)y^{k^2}y'$

$$\frac1{1+k^2}z'+p(x)z=q(x)$$
Which is a first order linear ODE, as desired.